# Clustering 3d scatter data using k-means clustering in matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, 3d, k-means, scatter

I have a 3d scatter plot organized in an array. When I plot my data as a 3d scatter plot, I obtain 2 clear clusters - one smaller one on the left and one large one on the right.
[image]

I've tried k-means clustering but I obtain these 2 clusters instead of the two that I wanted:
[image]

Here's my code:

```
opts = statset('Display','final');
[idx,C] = kmeans(data,2,'Distance','cityblock',...'Replicates',5,'Options',opts);
figure;
plot3(data(idx==1,1),data(idx==1,2),data(idx==1,3),'r.','MarkerSize',12)
plot3(data(idx==2,1),data(idx==2,2),data(idx==2,3),'b.','MarkerSize',12)
plot3(C(:,1),C(:,2),C(:,3),'cx',...'MarkerSize',15,'LineWidth',3)
legend('Cluster 1','Cluster 2','Centroids',...'Location','NW')
title 'Cluster Assignments and Centroids'
hold off
```

How can alter my code so that I obtain the 2 clusters (one small one on the left, one large one on the right), instead of the up-down cluster that I have right now? Thanks so much!

Comment: Is there a typo in plotting the centroids, `plot` vs `plot3`?

Comment: No, I don't think so..because plot3 is used for 3 arguments, but there are just 2 centroid arguments.

Comment: Well you should get 2 centroids, each being 3-Dimensional, otherwise there something very wrong.

Comment: Yes, as shown on the graph above, I did get 2 centroids. However, it didn't cluster the way that I was hoping it would, splitting left from right. Instead, it split up and down. I'm wondering how I can fix my code so that I can cluster it the way I want to?

Comment: I understand the question. Can you please state the values of your centroids? The reason I am asking is that they might simply not have been plotted correctly.

Comment: Just added the coordinates of the centroids in my question! Thanks!

Comment: This should tell you that there is something wrong, 3 3D vectors whichever way you are looking at them. It is hard tell which dimension is which but rows 1 and 3 look interesting to me, row 2 seems like a 3rd centroid somewhere in-between.

Comment: Hi, thanks for that observation. How would you suggest fixing my code? I am pretty new to k-means clustering. Thank you so much!

Comment: The problem is that k-means expects clusters to be of approximately the same size. That is not the case here. There are other clustering methods that do not make such assumptions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change to plot3 and add the C(:,3), This worked for me:

```
data=rand(100,3);
data=[data;2+rand(50,3)];

opts = statset('Display','final');
[idx,C] = kmeans(data,2,'Distance','cityblock','Replicates',5,'Options',opts);
figure(1);cla;gca;hold on;
plot3(data(idx==1,1),data(idx==1,2),data(idx==1,3),'r.','MarkerSize',12)
plot3(data(idx==2,1),data(idx==2,2),data(idx==2,3),'b.','MarkerSize',12)
plot3(C(:,1),C(:,2),C(:,3),'cx','MarkerSize',15,'LineWidth',3)
legend('Cluster 1','Cluster 2','Centroids','Location','NW')
title('Cluster Assignments and Centroids');
hold off
```

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for the centroid plotting help - that makes the centroid plot way better. However, it still clusters up and down (it splits the scatter plot up and down) instead of clustering the left cluster as one color and the right cluster as another. I'm wondering if I can change the clusters from up/down to left/right, if that makes sense. Thank you!

Comment: The algorithm does not know 'up' 'down' it only knows about distances between points in N-Dimensions (3 in your case). As previously mentioned you can try different distance metric, or if you can try different start locations `'Start','sample'`. If you know the rough locations you can even specify those. You can read up more about it in documentation [k-means](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/kmeans.html#namevaluepairarguments).

Comment: I see what you mean...do you have any suggestions for how I should change my k-means to get the left/right clusters that I want? Thank you again.

Comment: Try other distance function in: ('Distance','cityblock')

Answer (score 1):

Transform the left-right data *10 to add weight to the variable, this should result in the cluster split you intended